# Get column names to array in R

Tags: r

I have a database. How to get all of column name to array?

My code is:

```
library(foreign)
library(memisc)
data <- read.spss("data.sav", use.value.labels = FALSE, max.value.labels = 100)
Columns <- summary(data)
Columns[1]
```

out sample:

```
[1] "20582"
```

required output:

```
SubsID
print(Columns): 
                            Length Class  Mode     
SubsID                      20582  -none- numeric  
SubsID_RN                   20582  -none- character
responseid                  20582  -none- numeric
...
```

Comment: colnames(data) returns: NULL

Comment: But, names(data) work fine! :D Thanks instruction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `names(data)` [function](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/row.names.html).